# How to change the checked state of a ToolStripItem in Winforms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, contextmenu, toolstripitem

When I look it up, they list it as having a `.Checked` property. But both in Visual Studio and on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripitem.aspx), it doesn't list any kid of `Checked` property.

```
ContextMenuStrip menu = new ContextMenuStrip ( );
var menuItem = menu.Items.Add ( "CheckedItem" );
//menuItem.Checked?
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to cast to [`ToolStripMenuItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripmenuitem.aspx):

```
((ToolStripMenuItem)menuItem).Checked = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had 2 checked items on or off, so I used this format:

```
    private void onToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        offToolStripMenuItem.Checked = false;
    }

    private void offToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        onToolStripMenuItem.Checked = false;
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

This code will change StripMenuItem checked state after every mouse click.

**Note:** Tool Strip menu item name is: `uruchomZSystememToolStripMenuItem`

```cs
private void uruchomZSystememToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    uruchomZSystememToolStripMenuItem.Checked = !uruchomZSystememToolStripMenuItem.Checked;
}
```